# How to convert a dictionary to python dataclass where dict keys are dynamic?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dictionary as below where the keys are UUIDs. I would like to create a python dataclass for the below dictionaries. Thanks in advance.

```py
d = {
"d9376e0a-b4cc-4cbc-abc2-f8ce6648941c": "some value",
"d9376e0a-b4cc-4cbc-abc2-f8ce6648931d": "some value",
}
```

Also for the below dictionary where the keys are strings that contain only numeric values.

```py
percentages = {
"10": "some value",
"25": "some value",
"50": "some value"
}
```

Expecting python classes with dynamic variable names or something similar.

Comment: The keys in the first dictionary are not valid Python identifiers, how would you convert them to valid field names?

Comment: Honestly, a dictionary is the right kind of data structure for that kind of data. None of the keys you've shown in your examples are valid attribute names.

Comment: trust me, that's how our developers have written the response of APIs. Now, I am having trouble while doing serialisation in my test automation framework. :'(

Comment: you can add any attribute to any class as long as the attribute name is a valid identifier and the class isn't using `__slots__`.  When not using slots, all classes use a dict under the hood to track their attributes.  For the numeric ones you could just add a prefix such as `_10`. Still not clear that a data class is necessarily better than dict for your use case.  It could even just be a data class you stuff the existing dict in to as a single attribute.

Comment: all you need there are the dictionaires. Or some higher level classes that have methods to operate on _these_ dictionaries, that would then be kept, as they are, as attributes of objects of those classes.

There is no need to serialize or de-serializes these ditcs, because they are alread "de-serialized"  by json.loads - no need to "de-sreialize" further into a Python instance, which is what frameworks dealing with dataclasses do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need especially `dataclass` but sounds like [`make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) is what you are looking for.

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

d = {
  "d9376e0a-b4cc-4cbc-abc2-f8ce6648941c": "some value",
  "d9376e0a-b4cc-4cbc-abc2-f8ce6648931d": "some value",
  "10": "some value",
  "25": "some value",
  "50": "some value"
}

# update keys to avoid `TypeError: Field names must be valid identifiers` errors
# (your logic may be different)
def sanitize_key(val):
  _ = val.replace('-', '')
  return '_' + _ if _.startswith(('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')) else _

# create new class with necessary attributes
DataClass = make_dataclass('DataClass', [(sanitize_key(k), type(v)) for k, v in d.items()])

print('Class annotation:', DataClass.__annotations__)

# create instance of a dataclass
data_class_instance = DataClass(**{sanitize_key(k): v for k, v in d.items()})

# use an instance
print('Instance attributes:', [_attr for _attr in dir(data_class_instance) if not _attr.startswith('__')])
```

Output:

```
Class annotation: {'d9376e0ab4cc4cbcabc2f8ce6648941c': <class 'str'>, 'd9376e0ab4cc4cbcabc2f8ce6648931d': <class 'str'>, '_10': <class 'str'>, '_25': <class 'str'>, '_50': <class 'str'>}
Instance attributes: ['_10', '_25', '_50', 'd9376e0ab4cc4cbcabc2f8ce6648931d', 'd9376e0ab4cc4cbcabc2f8ce6648941c']
```

Comment: yes, this may "create a dataclass" out of the O.P. payloads, but it still will be a useless dataclass, since the attribute names can't be used as attributes, nor can be guessed at code-writting time, as they are themselves data, just available at runtime.